# Is there is possible way to return error message in http response (HandleHttpResponse processor)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a simple process, which starts with HandleHttpRequest then goes PublishKafka. After that, on success status I return responce code 200. On failure I want to return response with code 500 and with error message in the content. I have tried many ways, but I still don't know how can I do it. Is there is any possible way?

**UPDATE:**

When PublishKafka fail with some error message I need to send this error message in http response. I don't know how can I get this error message. There is no appropriate attribute in the flowfile. I have wanted to put the message in flowfile content. One of the possible resolutions is to use nifi-api or bulletin, but maybe there is more easiest way to do it.
[image: Nifi process]

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Please share a screenshot of your current flow and any errors you are encountering. You should be able to do this by using a `ReplaceText` or `UpdateAttribute` processor to set the HTTP response code depending on the _success_ or _failure_ relationship from the `PublishKafka` processor, or route to two separate `HandleHTTPResponse` processors.

Comment: Hello! I have updated the question and detailed my problem